# bug situation with Angular_Ng0303 *ngFor

Tags: angular-ng-if, angular-ng-class, angular-ngfor, angular-ng

I,ve been some days I started learning Angular, and now I'm having some troubles ([here's the problem](https://github.com/DNosheZ/situations.git)) when calling to the *ngForOf directive in a li, can someone help me?

pd: In the trouble picture, you can see the console bug alert, the others show the code that generate the issue.

A practic solution that allows me to print each requested array info in a list

Comment: Minor typo in your template: `let anim of animales`. `of`, not `for` after `anim`. Also, in the future, post all textual context as actual text instead of images.

Comment: Its better if you post the code or a link, you can use stackblitz or any online editor, your for is wrong, the correct form is `let anim of animales`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.